# How to copy define function to make 'n' variations of it? (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, function, copy

I need to make 'n' copies of this code:

```
ccfarray1=[]
def ccf1(binnum):
    for i in datarange:
        ccf=((a[i]-xbar)*(c[(i-binnum)]-ybar))/(norm*stdevx*stdevy)
        parray.append(ccf)
        calc=sum(parray)
    ccfarray1.append(calc)
    del parray[:]
    return ccfarray1
```

so that for example one copy of it is is:

```
ccfarray2=[]
def ccf2(binnum):
    for i in datarange:
        ccf=((a[i]-xbar)*(c[(i-binnum)]-ybar))/(norm*stdevx*stdevy)
        parray.append(ccf)
        calc=sum(parray)
    ccfarray2.append(calc)
    del parray[:]
    return ccfarray2
```

Whereby each time a new array is made, ccfarray'n'.

I need this like 20 times, but that's a lot of copying and pasting. Is there an elegant solution to code this and if I need to change the number of times I need it.

I need a lot of these because I'm  treating them as bins. If 'binnum' falls between a certain range, then I need it to be appended to a different array than if binnum fell between a different range.

If there is code that can do this without so much code than thats fine, but I don't know how to do that!

Comment: What?.. Why do you need 20 functions doing the same thing?..

Comment: Could you just move your empty list inside of the function body and then only have one function? You may have 20 variables with different results, but you shouldn't need 20 functions that do the same thing.

Comment: I need them because I'm treating them as bins. If 'binnum' falls between a certain range, then I need it to be appended to a different array than if binnum fell between a different range.

Comment: Then you need a collection of arrays, and for your function to use `binnum` to decide which one to use.

Comment: How do I make a collection of arrays, can't really find anything on here about it. Or do you mean just manually write out 20 arrays? Which wouldn't be great because if I choose new data, more arrays may be needed and I want my code to run as if all I need to do is change data and run code without messing around with parameters.

Comment: Where are the variables: `a`, `xbar`, `c`, `ybar`, `norm`, `stdevx`,`stdevy`,`parray`,`datarange` defined?  Your "function" looks like its modifying some global variables which isn't a good way to write your program.  ...and you definitely don't want 20 functions that do the same thing!  You need to think some more about how to structure this.

Comment: I think the issue we are having is seeing the duplicative functions - it immediately makes one think about how to reduce it into one (part of the benefit of functions in general). As @Gerrat says, I would suggest looking at the structure of your code and figuring out how to set it up in such a way that your function returns the desired result based on `binnum`, and you handle further parsing after that.

Comment: This has been good advice, I think I may have been a little silly in my approach to do what I needed. Thanks guys! First crack at using stackoverflow and it's been real helpful.

Comment: Does anyone know how I can make 'n' number of empty lists with different names without manually typing them all out? Would make a new question but I'm new here and I don't know whether there is a limit on questions (or if it's annoying for loads of questions to be asked)?

Comment: What I mean by "a collection of arrays" is to make a list, and put as many lists in it as you want. For example, `ccfarrays = [[], [], []]`. Then instead of using `ccfarray1`, `ccfarray2`, etc, you use `ccfarrays[0]`, `ccfarrays[1]`, etc. Or if you want to access them by name rather than number you could have `ccfarrays = {'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': []}`, and then your access pattern is `ccfarrays['a']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not completely sure what you want to do with your functions but you can create functions inside closure, and than put them as items to some list, like this:

```
def get_functions(count):
    ccfarrays=map(lambda: [], range(count))
    def get_nth_func(n):
        def ccf1(binnum):
            for i in datarange:
                ccf=((a[i]-xbar)*(c[(i-binnum)]-ybar))/(norm*stdevx*stdevy)
                parray.append(ccf)
                calc=sum(parray)
            ccfarray[n].append(calc)
            del parray[:]
            return ccfarray[n]
        return ccf1
    return map(get_nth_func, range(count)
```

So, if you want 20 functions you just create them like this:

```
f = get_functions(20)
```

and than call them like this:

```
f[6](binnum)
```

Comment: Haven't tested it, but creating a list like `ccfarrays=[[]] * count` will actually make each element the same, so future appending to one element will actually affect all of them. Not sure if that is accounted for later in your code - I may not be smart enough to grasp the formulas :)

Comment: @Bunyk That looks better - you could even try `ccfarrays = [[] for _ in range(count)]` if you wanted to avoid the lambdas :)

Comment: @RocketDonkey I guess you are right, list comprehensions are more pythonic.